# react input onkeypress not work in ie10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, reactjs

As the title. i use react to build a component, like this:

`<div className={rootClassName} style={style}>
    <InputElem {...others}
    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
</div>`

and handleKeyPress:

`handleKeyPress = (event) => { .. const value = event.target.value}`

and InputElem you can think it's always input 
it good at chrome but onkeypress do not work at ie10. 
Did some one can help me ?
i try to add attribute tabindex on div but nor work so good. 
thank you. and i not good at english. i try my best to do it.

Comment: How about use `Input` instead of `InputElem`? 
`<InputElem {...others}><Input onKeyPress={...} /></InputElem>`

Comment: No，the InputElem compoment can be textarea and input.  thankyou for you proposal

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Try to replace arrow function by normal one. `handleKeyPress = function(event) { .. const value = event.target.value}`

Comment: thankyou, i cant find the reason，but i use babel loose mode。 it work fine in ie10. thankyou so much ！ this is the first time I use the stackoverflow . and i feel the power of internet.